# Quantum operation and non-trace-preserving

Tags: quantum-operation

In Chapter 8 of Nielsen and Chuang's Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, a mathematical framework is developed to provide a realization of the quantum operation $\mathcal{E}$ with operation elements $\{E_k\}$. Here is a picture of a section [image]

My question it's about how to construct a unitary operator for a system–environment model of a non-trace-preserving quantum operation, by introducing an extra operator, $E_\infty$, such that when we introduce $k=\infty$ then we get $\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k=I$. I think is similar to the process in the picture but with the new element.

Comment: it seems to me like you are asking how to construct a Kraus representation $\Phi(\rho)=\sum_k E_k\rho E_k^\dagger$ for a non-trace-preserving map $\Phi$ with $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k=I$. Any such map is automatically trace-preserving. You can have a Kraus representation for a non-trace-preserving map, this amounts to dropping the condition $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k=I$.

Comment: Unitaries are always trace preserving. If you want a non-trace preserving operation, you'll need to simulate it with some sort of unitary + measurement where you throw away the system on some particular outcome. But that's not really what your question seems to be asking...